# Trouble using BeautifulSoup to parse HTML

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble parsing some html using beautifulsoup.

In this piece of HTML for example, I want to extract the Target Text.  More HTML in the HTML code is like this so I want to extract all the Target Texts.  I also want to extract the "tt0082971" and put that number and the Target Text in two rows of a tab-delimted file.  The numbers after 'tt' change for every instance of Target Text.

```
<td class="target">
      <span class="wlb_wrapper" data-caller-name="search" data-size="small" data-tconst="tt0082971">
      </span>
      <a href="/target/tt0082971/">
       Target Text 1
      </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup.select` accepts [CSS Selectors](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = '''
... <td class="target">
...       <span class="wlb_wrapper" data-caller-name="search" data-size="small" data-tconst="tt0082971">
...       </span>
...       <a href="/target/tt0082971/">
...        Target Text 1
...       </a>
...       </td>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> for td in soup.select('td.target'):
...     span = td.select('span.wlb_wrapper')
...     if span:
...         print span[0].get('data-tconst') # To get `tt0082971`
...     print td.a.text.strip() # To get target text
...
tt0082971
Target Text 1
```